# How do I run an external file in soapui and take the output and set it as header

Tags: groovy, soapui

I would like to run an external .bat file using groovy script in soapUI. also would like to use the output generated from the external file as the value for the header

here is the script that I am using to run the bat file

```
String line
def p = "cmd /c C:\\Script\\S1.bat".execute()
def bri = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))
while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {log.info line}
```

here is the content of the bat file

```
java -jar SignatureGen.jar -pRESOURCE -nRandomString -mGET -d/api/discussion-streams/metadata -teyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJjbGllbnQiOiIxIiwicm9sZSI6IllGQURNSU4iLCJleHAiOjI3NTgzMjU2MDIsInRpIjo3MjAwNiwiaWF0IjoxNTU4MzI1NjAyLCJwZXJzb24iOiI1In0.bbci7ZBWmPsANN34Ris9H0-mosKF2JLTZ-530Rex2ut1kjCwprZr_196N-K1alFBH_A9pbG0MPspaDOnvOKOjA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
def p = "ls -la".execute()

def err = new StringBuffer()
def out = new StringBuffer()
p.waitForProcessOutput(out, err)

p.waitForOrKill(5000)
int ret = p.exitValue()

// optionally check the exit value and err for errors 

println "ERR: $err"
println "OUT: $out"

// if you want to do something line based with the output
out.readLines().each { line -> 
  println "LINE: $line"
}
```

is based on linux, but translates to windows by just replacing the `ls -la` with your bat file invocation `cmd /c C:\\Script\\S1.bat`.

This executes the process, calls [waitForProcessOutput](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.2/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html#waitForProcessOutput(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.StringBuffer)) to make sure the process doesn't block and that we are saving away the stdout and stderr streams of the process, and then waits for the process to finish using [waitForOrKill](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.2/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html#waitForOrKill(long)).

After the `waitForOrKill` the process has either been terminated because it took too long, or it has completed normally. Whatever the case, the `out` variable will contain the output of the command. To figure out whether or not there was an error during bat file execution, you can inspect the `ret` and `err` variables.

I chose the `waitForOrKill` timeout at random, adjust to fit your needs. You can also use `waitFor` without a timeout which will wait until the process completes, but it is generally better to set some timeout to make sure your command doesn't execute indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however how I can capture the output and assign it to a variable

Comment: The variable `out` in the above code contains the output. It's of type StringBuffer and if you need the variable in a String instance instead you can for example do: `def strOut = out.toString()` which would give you a variable `strOut` of type `java.lang.String` with the output from the bat file execution.